# Saving new excel file in file directory specified in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I have some code that copies data from one main workbook and pastes it into a new worksheet. I want to have the code save this new excel file in a specific directory, specified in a cell within a page. I run into the "Run-time error '1004'" and not sure of a work around. I have some code below that shows what I have currently. The data in the cell `A11` is `C:\Users\MY.NAME\Desktop\Data.xls`

```
 Dim Source2, StrFile2 As String

    Source = Workbooks("Main Workbook").Sheets("Directory Location").Range("A11").Value2
    StrFile = Dir(Source)

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Source2 & StrFile2
```

Comment: `Dim Source2, StrFile2 As String` will `Dim` `Source2` as a variant. Try `Dim`ming as a `String`. Also, in line two, you are using `Source` instead of `Source2` and in line 3 `StrFile` instead of `StrFile2`

Comment: Ah yea that was my issue actually. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't let me ask a clarifying question. If you're just trying to copy the workbook to the location that you have in cell `A11`, this works for me. Be sure to change the extension in cell `A11` to `xlsm`

```
Sub fff()
    Dim Source2, StrFile2 As String
    Source2 = Range("A11").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Source2
End Sub
```